# jquery getting value of select

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="MyClass"></div>
<div class="MyClass"></div>
<div class="MyClass"></div>

<div class="MyClass">
....stuff
  <select>
    <option value="1">blahblah</option>
    <option value="2">blahblah</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="MyClass">
....stuff
  <select>
    <option value="5">blahblah</option>
    <option value="10">blahblah</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have several divs of class MyClass and some of these divs have a select box inside.

I have the following javascript that's used to trigger an event:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $('.MyClass').click(function () { DoThing($(this)); }); 
});
```

The DoThing function looks like this:

```
function DoThing(TheDiv) {
  var Value = parseInt(TheDiv.find(select).val());
  alert(Value);
}
```

That's the part I'm struggling on: how do I find the value of the select that's selected? For now, it alerts only 1.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: could I inquire as to why you are grabbing the value of the SELECT list on click of the DIV that contains it?  As you may or may not know, that value will be assigned to your VAR before the user has a chance to change it. (as it is triggered once a user clicks the DropDown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it (assuming that there always is exactly one `select` per `.MyClass`):

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('.MyClass').click(function() {
        val = $('select', this).val();
        alert(val);
    }); 
});
```

Bonus: [The working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Tqrg/)

---

**Edit:**

Also, Betard Fooser's comment is absolutely worth noting. The better way to bind the handler would be:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('.MyClass select').change(function() {
        val = $(this).val();
        alert(val);
    }); 
});
```

---

*No need to read on from here, just a typo caught*

Also, your binding is missing a closing bracket and thus won't work:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $('.MyClass').click(function () { DoThing($(this); });
//                                                 ^
//                                Missing ")" here |
});
```

So, if you try

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $('.MyClass').click(function () { DoThing($(this)); }); 
});
```

instead, things should work pretty nicely.

Comment: @BetardFooser It's not not**h**ing, it's *noting*, mate! ;)

Comment: @vzwick my sincerest apologies... apparently my reading skills first thing in the morning before my first coffee are worthless.  Sorry dude, total goof on my part.

Comment: @BetardFooser You're welcome, that state is all too familiar to me.

Answer (score 5):

#### Description

You should use jQuery's `:selected` selector to get the selected option.

Check out my sample and this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/yyASx/)

#### Sample

**Html**

```
  <select id="firstSelect">
    <option value="5">blahblah</option>
    <option selected="true" value="10">blahblah</option>
  </select>
  <select id="secondSelect">
    <option value="5">blahblah</option>
    <option selected="true" value="14">blahblah</option>
  </select>
  <select id="thirdSelect">
    <option value="5">blahblah</option>
    <option selected="true" value="20">blahblah</option>
  </select>
```

**jQuery**

```
alert($("#firstSelect option:selected").val());
alert($("#secondSelect option:selected").val());
alert($("#thirdSelect option:selected").val());
```

#### More Information

- [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/yyASx/)
- [jQuery :selected Selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)
- [jQuery.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: Although I realize that your fiddle is but a demonstration, take a look at this scenario here: http://jsfiddle.net/yyASx/1/ – not pretty, huh?

Comment: Absolutely, this was just a sample. You should assign a unique id to your selects. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/yyASx/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
var selectedValues = [];    
$("select option:selected").each(function () {
   selectedValues.push(parseInt($(this).val(), 10));
});
```

Comment: .val() basically does just that and is the better way to go.

Comment: Well val gets the first selected value, the question had multiple select statements which should be handled.

Comment: Okay, I might have misunderstood the question … If it is what you think it is, you're right about the `$.each()`. Still, `parseInt($(this).text())` is a pretty … err … creative approach, since `$.each()` passes you one element at a time and `text()` is definitely not what you're looking for anyways. Oh, also, you should **never ever use `parseInt()` without an explicit base** (like `parseInt(x, 10)`) or you will run into big trouble. Try `parseInt('08')' vs. `parseInt('08', 10)` and see for yourself.

Comment: @vzwick is correct...  in your example Abhi you are using .text() which retrieves the text/label show in the dropdown, not the VALUE defined.

Comment: Updated the code to use the val() instead of text, also used an array to capture the values in an array

Answer (score 1):

Using `select option:selected` will return the desired result:

```
function DoThing(TheDiv) {
    var Value = TheDiv.find('select option:selected').val();
    alert(Value);
}
```

Also `DoThing` is missing a `)` before the first `;`.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the documentation. *"Get the **current** value of the **first element** in the set of matched elements*." means that `$('#some-select').val();` is equivalent to `$('#some-select').first().val()`, rather than `$('#some-select option').first().val()` like you suggested.

Comment: Correct and bad on my part. I will update my response. Thanks. Also, that's even show as an example in the documentation:

$('select.foo option:selected').val(); // get the value from a dropdown select
$('select.foo').val(); // get the value from a dropdown select even easier